# Check some words with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to check some words with `preg_match`. If the words contain numbers and `.`, I want to echo "ok".

Lets say i want to ckeck this :

```
4814.84dszs  //ok
412.84.61.412  //ok
hello.4you //ok
welcome.user //not ok
481221222 // not ok
```

I have used this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9][.]+$/', 'MY_WORD_HERE'))
{
echo 'ok';
}
```

But it doesn't give me the exactly result which I looking for.

Comment: What result does it give you?

Comment: what are you getting .. ?

Comment: you forgot + change pattern to: `/^[0-9]+[.]$/`

Comment: can you show some example of these words?

Comment: I want to check ip 128.142.124.41 i don't want to check if it have ip format or not..just if it have numbers and (.)

Comment: you're requiring the text to be a **SINGLE** digit at the start of the string, followed by one or more `.`, and nothing else. e.g. `1...` would match. `12..` would not.

Comment: Check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
if (preg_match('/(\d+\.)|(\.\d+)/', '4814.84dszs'))
{
echo 'ok';
}
```

`^` -> indicates at the begining of the string

`$` -> End of the string.

So your pattern says from start to end(Matching for whole string)

If you remove this it will match anywhere in the string not whole string.

Comment: In question : `if (preg_match('/^[0-9][.]+$/', 'MY_WORD_HERE'))`

Comment: His question says : `If the words contain numbers and .,` not the whole word.

Comment: yes I got it, but when using preg_match must write full pattern because it's not like preg_match_all

Comment: @PrasanthBendra but this will echo ok even if the word contain numbers only without (.)

Comment: I guess, if you want to match for digits and dots in a string, my answer will work, I don't understood `"full pattern"`

Comment: @user2203703 : In that case I think Akam's answer will work for you, But in that I suggest to remove `^` and `$`

Comment: `4814.84dszs
412.84.61.412
hello.4you` -> For all these case you want `"ok"` to be printed ?

Comment: @user2203703 : Updated the answer it works fine with all your strings :D

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if (preg_match('/([0-9]+[\.]+|[\.]+[0-9]+)$/', 'MY_WORD_HERE'))
{
echo 'ok';
}
```

"+" (plus sign) means 1 or more occurrences of the matched expression

You can also use this if the . and the numbers are not following each other and there are other chars in the middle:

```
if (preg_match('/([0-9]+[^0-9\.]*[\.]+|[\.]+[^0-9\.]*[0-9]+)$/', 'MY_WORD_HERE'))
{
echo 'ok';
}
```

**Explanation:**  it checks if there is a digit followed by dot or if there's a dot followed by a digit or even if there's a digit followed by other chars then a dot or vice versa.

Comment: I wish if i could accept more 1 answer..up vote..Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
        $pattern = '%(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\.)%';
        if (preg_match($pattern, 'MY_WORD_HERE'))
        {
           echo 'ok';
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: @user2203703 sorry I am bit late .. anyways I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '#^([\d]{1,3})([.][\d]{1,3})([.][\d]{1,3})([.][\d]{1,3})$#';
```